# Dplyr doesn't respect groups when ranking data

Tags: r, dplyr

Using the below code in dplyr 0.7.6, I try to calculate the rank of a variable for each day on a dataset. But dplyr doesn't account for the `group_by(CREATIONDATE_DAY)`

```
dates <- sample(seq(from=as.POSIXct("2019-03-12",tz="UTC"),to=as.POSIXct("2019-03-20",tz="UTC"),by = "day"),size = 100,replace=TRUE)
group <- sample(c("A","B","C"),100,TRUE)

df <- data.frame(CREATIONDATE_DAY = dates,GROUP = group)
# calculate the occurances for each day and group
dfMod <- df %>% group_by(CREATIONDATE_DAY,GROUP) %>%
                dplyr::summarise(COUNT = n()) %>% ungroup()
# Compute the rank by count for each day
dfMod <- dfMod %>% group_by(CREATIONDATE_DAY) %>%
                   mutate(rank = rank(-COUNT, ties.method ="min"))
```

But the rank values are calculate on the entire group instead on the creation day value. As seen in the image the row with id 24 should be rank 1 due to 4 being the highest value for 16.03.2019 and row 23 should be rank 2 of this particular day. Where is my mistake?

[image]

**Edit**: added desired output:

[image]

Edit #2: as MrFlick has pointed out I checked my dplyr version (0.7.6) and upgrade to the most current version fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Your example uses randomly generated data. Use `set.seed()` so we can get the same random values otherwise it's very difficult to verify or reproduce your results.

Comment: It seems to work just fine looking at `View(dfMod %>% arrange(CREATIONDATE_DAY, -COUNT))`

Comment: The values shown here are just test values. Any arbitrary values will return the same result and are verifiable within 2 seconds. My question targets the fact why the rank function ranks the data over the group column rather the creationdate_day column

Comment: @MrFlick sorry, maybe I didn't state my question clearly. I added an image to show what I try to achieve

Comment: @user3394605 Your dataset isn't sorted by `CREATIONDATE_DAY`, which probably gave rise to the confusion. The rank function ranks but doesn't re-sort. If you follow MrFlick's suggestion to sort the rows before viewing, you should get what you want.

Comment: I see a couple problems: (1) you haven't given a reproducible example; (2) it is not clear what's wrong based on what little you've shown us. When I run your code (with my own random start) and verify the ranking (using MrFlick's `arrange`), it is correct. Please redo your code after you use `set.seed`.

Comment: What version of `dplyr` are you using? I tested with `dplyr_0.8.0.1`

Comment: @MrFlick thanks that was the key. I had version dplyr_0.7.6 running. After upgrading it worked as expected. If you can type this out as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that may be are some conflict with another package. If you have active `lubridate`, try to inverse the order in which you call the packages `lubridate` and `dplyr` (I've tried your example and gave me the right answer). Yet, you can stil try with:

```
dfMod <- dfMod %>% group_by(CREATIONDATE_DAY) %>% mutate(rank = row_number(desc(COUNT)))
> head(dfMod)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   CREATIONDATE_DAY [2]
  CREATIONDATE_DAY    GROUP COUNT  rank
  <dttm>              <fct> <int> <int>
1 2019-03-12 00:00:00 A         2     3
2 2019-03-12 00:00:00 B         5     1
3 2019-03-12 00:00:00 C         4     2
4 2019-03-13 00:00:00 A         4     1
5 2019-03-13 00:00:00 B         3     2
6 2019-03-13 00:00:00 C         2     3
```